# Error using connector Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, connector

I am currently using matlab 2016a, I have encountered this error when i tried to open up my simulink project.
Environment variable had also been change according to these steps but still did not work out:

***Set the Enviornment Variable: JAVA_TOOL_OPTION to -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true.
Reset the computer to enable the change***

```
Error using connector.ensureServiceOn
    Error starting MATLAB Connector. Please check that port 31515 is available.

    Error in slmsgviewer

    Error in slmsgviewer/PersistentInstance

    Error in slmsgviewer.processRecord

    Error in slxPackager/registerHandler

    Error in slxPackager/executeLoadCallbacks

    Error in slprivate (line 11)
       [varargout{1:nargout}] = feval(function_name, varargin{1:end});

    Error in openmdl (line 12)
        evalin('base', ['open_system(''' strrep(filename, '''','''''') ''');'] );

    Error in openslx (line 9)
    out = openmdl(filename);

    Error in open (line 158)
                feval(openAction,fullpath);

    Error in uiopen (line 167)
                open(fn);
```

Please advice on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when MATLAB is blocked by some firewall from connecting to Internet. MATLAB uses Internet during simulation. Just exclude it from firewall and there you go. There will be no error.